# No electric power on my motorcycle

Tags: electrical, motorcycle

I bought a 2001 Yamaha roadmaster silverado 1600 yesterday. At the guys house it fired up fine. I went back a couple of hours later and bought it. I fired it up and drove it about 30 miles home. Everything seemed fine. After I was home a couple of hours I was going to go for a ride and went to start it... nothing! No electrical power. No lights, no gauges, no nothing. I am not sure what is wrong. I haven’t been able to locate the electrical fuse box yet. Do any of you have an idea what could be wrong or where the fuse panel may be? Thanks

Comment: It could be a loose connection on a battery terminal, check to make sure those are tight before you look at anything else.

Comment: Did you leave the lights on? All too easy on a new ride... Check the battery voltage.

Comment: I did. It is tight. And the battery is charged and good.

Comment: So what is the battery voltage?

Comment: 12.7 volts..........

Comment: Call the seller, make sure there's no hidden immobilizer or switch you need to be aware of.

Comment: I figured it out. Starter relay. I replaced it and it started for about two seconds and stopped. Now it will turn over but will not start again. Ugh!!!!

Comment: You could add what happened to your question, OR,  you could even answer this question yourself and make a new question :-).   We love having clear Questions and Answers in the end, even if things get started in Comments.

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out. New starter relay failed. Replaced it and back in the road!  Thanks for all of your input!!